# VirtualBox: Windows XP BSOD 0x0000007B

Tags: windows-xp, virtualbox, virtual-machine, bsod

[edit] Quick answer from [comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1616484/virtualbox-windows-xp-bsod-0x0000007b#comment2466003_1616484) which I believe is true:

> There is probably no realistic answer when the computer hardware does not support hardware virtualization. You will need to upgrade the machine to do what you want.

---

I tried to install Windows XP x86 in Oracle VirtualBox v6.0.14

After (seemingly) successful installation, on first (and each) boot BSOD with 0x0000007B occurs, which indicates that Windows is not seeing the disk hardware it was installed on.

Multiple posts across Internet report that problem gets resolved with Storage Device Controller set to IDE PIIX3. Some reported PIIX4, also try-to-pick-what-works-for-you has been suggested.
https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=57466#p266748 gives somewhat opposite info:

> There can be many reasons why it can't find the boot disk: the disk controller type change is one of them (it usually isn't necessary to play around with different IDE chipsets, PIIX4 should be fine

I have tried all three PIIX4, PIIX3, ICH6 available,
tried reinstalling from scratch with PIIX3 selected before I run VM for the first time,
— I get the same 0x0000007B

The difference is that people mostly run into 0x0000007B on migrating/upgrading, whereas I get it on fresh installation.

Host OS: [antiX](https://antixlinux.com/) 19 GNU/Linux which is Debian 10 Buster with [runit](http://smarden.org/runit/) instead of systemd
Hardware: Lenovo 3000 G530 laptop, 2008 manufacture year, hardware virtualization is not supported.

Also I wonder:

1. Settings → System → Motherboard → Chipset
   PIIX3 and ICH9 are available,
   — this PIIX3 and PIIX3 of Storage Device Controller — are these settings interdependent?
2. Why only 32-bit options for guest machines for all OSes are available whereas the host is 64-bit?

Comment: “Why only 32-bit options for guest machines for all OSes are available whereas the host is 64-bit?” - This means hardware virtualization is disabled.  However, since Windows XP is 32-bit only, it isn’t necessarily required.

Comment: Try updating Virtual Box to the current version to see if that helps. Then review the suggestions in this VBOX article: Vhttps://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=83318

Comment: @John In the latest 6.1.16-140961 I am left without the tickbox for disabling hardware virtualization, "Invalid settings detected" insists on disabling, so OK button is unavailable, no VM can be configured. Thus, latest 6.1.16-140961 on my installation is totally useless https://i.ibb.co/WFR3f6d/vbox6-1-Screenshot-2021-01-11-17-59-48.png

Comment: There is probably no realistic answer when the computer hardware does not support hardware virtualization. You will need to upgrade the machine to do what you want.

Comment: @John AFAIK, hardware virtualization has to do with the processor, not storage. 0x0000007B has to do with storage, not hardware virtualization. In v6.0.14 I do have the tickbox between Paravirtualization Interface and Enable Nested paging. Please correct me if I misunderstand.

Comment: I have not found any answer to your issue. I have XP machines here running in more modern hardware with VMware Workstation as the host. All is well that way.

Comment: Trying slipstreaming drivers into XP.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PFW7O6bAN5Q   There are other tools that can do a similar thing.  You really only need storage, but I recommend chipset drivers as well.

Answer (score 0):

Ripped from  https://www.minitool.com/backup-tips/0x0000007b.html :

"What Causes the BSOD 0x0000007B?

The STOP 0x0000007B error often occurs on Blue Screen of Death. So what causes the BSOD 0x0000007B? The causes are shown below:

```
Missing or corrupted bootloader files.
Incorrect BIOS configuration.
Boot sector virus.
Damaged Registry.
Corrupted EFI bootloader.
Hard drive failure.
```

"

Means: turn on the virtualization on, check hw-settings (not more than 4gb RAM f.ex.), look about cpu-settings, and so on.
then check your ISO or Image, then check your virtual harddisk (you may want to recreate it to make sure, everything is ok - an doublecheck the path).

If you like to, just recreate the whole maschine, sometimes it helps. :)

Comment: I have triple-checked the settings and quadruple-recreated the whole machine. Sometimes something else is needed in order to help...

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to add an IDE controller and select your Windows XP iso and do NOT use an SCSI controller.

If you already have the SCSI controller, DELETE it and add the IDE instead.

Comment: I get IDE by default. Thanks for trying anyway